# Using ngx-treeview Angular 16

Tags: angular, ngx-treeview, angular-migration

I'm trying to migrate Angular from 12 version to 16 and I have a package ngx-treeview, last update was for 10 version but it was used for 12 as well but it doesn't work now at all. I have an error
`This likely means that the library (ngx-treeview) which declares TreeviewModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.`
Maybe it might be fixed in some way or only removing this package?

I tried resolve this problem by myself by importing module in app module (before it was used in custom Angular lib which was created by ng g lib
Also I investigated and researched how I can fix it by myself

Comment: The repo seems like it is not updated for the last couple of years, the last commit was on Jul 7, 2020, and if you want to use Ivy then the library probably needs updates. So I would think you are out of luck, you might be forced to use another library to handle your tree view, is your best path of action.

Comment: @NilsKähler thank you a lot. I'll use angular material tree

Answer (score 0):

As I got from comment and google as well, it's better to use some another library. In my case I'll use angular material tree.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few different implementations of ngx-treeview on npm, I found one that had been updated reasonably recently and it worked. Might be worth a look see if you wish to use a ngx-treeview tree.

https://npm.io/search/keyword%3Angx-treeview/2